# Find first and last name of a user in a github repo

Tags: json, github-api

I have an organization in Github.com and there are several users making contributions to my organization's repo. I would like to know the first and last name of the users in my organization. Any github api that does this?

Answer (score 3):

You should combine the [**Contributors** endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors) with [the **Users** endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user) from GitHub API, since the contributors endpoint does *not* expose the `name` field in the response.

> #### List contributors
>
> List contributors to the specified repository, sorted by the number of commits per contributor in descending order.

So, let's suppose your repository is located at `owner/repo`, you will make a `GET` request to this url:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/contributors
```

For example, this will fetch the contributors in my `git-stats` project:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/IonicaBizau/git-stats/contributors
```

This will give you a reponse like this:

```
[
  {
    "login": "IonicaBizau",
    "id": 2864371,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2864371?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/IonicaBizau",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "contributions": 238
  },
  ...
]
```

As you can see, the full name is *not* exposed here. To get the user full name, you have to make additional requests for each contributor, using [the Users endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user). For example, for `IonicaBizau` you will make a request to:

```
https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau
```

The response object has a `name` field which contains the full name of the user.

Example:

```
{
  "login": "IonicaBizau",
  "id": 2864371,
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2864371?v=3",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/IonicaBizau",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IonicaBizau/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "name": "Ionică Bizău",
  "company": "jillix",
  "blog": "http://ionicabizau.net",
  "location": "Romania",
  "email": "contact@ionicabizau.net",
  "hireable": true,
  "bio": null,
  "public_repos": 223,
  "public_gists": 1,
  "followers": 619,
  "following": 77,
  "created_at": "2012-11-22T15:51:02Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-10-14T09:43:43Z"
}
```

So, summarizing, to get the users' full names for a given repository like `owner/repo` you have to:

```
 GET https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/contributors
 foreach contributor in contributors
    GET https://api.github.com/users/<contributor.login>
      // Do something with <user.name>
```